# Можно ли узнать откуда перемещается(копируется) файл в другой каталог?

Tags: windows, файловая-система

В общем задача такая, нужно перехватить и перенаправить файл. Например я из папки 'A'  перемещаю файл в папку 'B', и мне нужно перехватить файл до того как он переместиться и перенаправить его в 'C'.
Есть FileSystemWatcher, но он даёт только информацию из каталога который мы отслеживаем, то бишь 'B'. И вот вопрос как это можно сделать, и можно ли сделать такое вообще

И возможно ли каким-то образом получить полный путь к файлу, который пользователь хочет переместить, и отменить процесс перемещения?